# How to call escape function from controller in symfony2

Tags: symfony, xss

How to call the escape function from controllers in symfony2? For view files (PHP engine) it is called like:

```
Hello <?php echo $view->escape($name) ?>
```

I need to send an html snip-set to view and escape some variables from XSS attack. Is this escape function is just a [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)() or [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)(). If it is not possible then I will have to call htmlspecialchars for it.

Comment: The symfony escape function is running htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES)

Comment: Are you using Twig for templates?

Comment: @PeterBailey, it is PHP Engine.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at:

```
// Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine.php
htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, $that->getCharset(), false)
```

So yes, ultimately htmlspecialchars is used.  PhpEngine also supports escaping other types of outputs such as javascript.

However, you should really try to avoid generating html in a controller.  Take the time to move it to a php template and let the templater worry about that sort of stuff.

I did take some time to see if it was possible to just grab the engine itself but it is not directly exposed as a service.  You could do this: $engine = $this->get('templating')->getEngine($name) but sadly getEngine() is protected.  So I don't know of any obvious way to get the engine.

But again, best to just let the template engine work as designed.